# Restore BitBox Wallet from Backup Key + Pass in Software

Tags: cryptography, cryptocurrency, wallet

I have an export (64-character Hex Key (256 bits) + Password) from a BitBox 1.0 Feathercoin (FTC) wallet.
I do not have any functional BitBox 1.0 Hardware and would like to access that wallet.

How could I access the wallet using software alone?

I have tried to restore on the Basis of BIP38 tools and tried to use Electrum FTC. But it did not work.